# Random shuffle list becomes None

Tags: python, nonetype

```
import random

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
# random.shuffle(a) # this is fine
a = random.shuffle(a) # a is now None
```

I made a typo in my code but I'd like to know in this case why a turns into None. What's going on under the hood?

Comment: random.shuffle(a) this is enough no need to assign it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) works in-place, it does not return anything (And hence by default it returns `None` , since all Python function calls should return some value)  , hence when you do - `a = random.shuffle(a)` , `a` becomes None. Try -

```
random.shuffle(a)
```

From documentation of `random.shuffle` -

> **`random.shuffle(x[, random])`**
>
> **Shuffle the sequence x in place.** The optional argument random is a 0-argument function returning a random float in [0.0, 1.0); by default, this is the function [random()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.random).

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: I know what you mean, but IMHO saying that "it does not return anything" is a little misleading, since it returns `None`. Maybe you should mention that _all_ Python functions _must_ return something, functions without an explicit `return` statement return `None`, and it's conventional for functions that mutate objects in-place to return `None`.

Comment: You are right thanks, added that as well.